# Problems related with Texlive 2013 Installation

Tags: latex, texlive

I have installed Texlive 2013 by burning it on a DVD. However after using tlmgr a few times to get the updates done I have been running into problems in every apt-get command I invoke. I have uninstalled everything related with TexLive then did a clean installation again via DVD. However after I installed  the editor Texmaker the problem reoccurred. What may be the reason behind this and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance for your contribution. The message is as follows:

```
Reading state information... Done
gnuplot is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
16 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up texlive-base (2009-15) ...
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVE... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvips'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvips' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvipdfmx'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvipdfmx' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig xdvi'
texconfig: try `texconfig xdvi' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig pdftex'
texconfig: try `texconfig pdftex' for help
texconfig: unknown option `paperconf' given as argument for `texconfig dvips'
texconfig: try `texconfig dvips' for help
dpkg: error processing texlive-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-base:
 texlive-latex-base depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kile:
 kile depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing kile (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended isNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                     not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pgf:
 pgf depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 pgf depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing pgf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on pgf (>= 1.00-1); however:
  Package pgf is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-generic-recommended:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 texlive-generic-recommended depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-generic-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-pstricks:
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-generic-recommended (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-generic-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive-pstricks depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-pstricks (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prosper:
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-pstricks; however:
  Package texlive-pstricks is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing prosper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-fonts-recommended:
 texlive-fonts-recommended depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-fonts-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-fonts-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-extra-utils:
 texlive-extra-utils depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-extra-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-font-utils:
 texlive-font-utils depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-font-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-luatex:
 texlive-luatex depends on texlive-base (>= 2009-1); however:
  Package texlive-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-luatex (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tipa:
 tipa depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-base
 texlive-latex-base
 kile
 texlive-latex-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 pgf
 latex-beamer
 texlive-generic-recommended
 texlive-pstricks
 prosper
 texlive-fonts-recommended
 texlive
 texlive-extra-utils
 texlive-font-utils
 texlive-luatex
```

tipa

Comment: You have TL2009. _Either_ stick with the version from Ubuntu _or_ use vanilla TL2013. And please file a bug report against Ubuntu about this old TL.

Comment: Forgive my inexperience, how can I file a bug report and uninstall the former TL? I think I have installed TL 2013.